# Differences between 20.04 and 21.10 boot images

Tags: boot, filesystem

I try to install Ubuntu on quite new Dell laptops. If I write a bootable USB drive from 21.10 image I cannot boot. I get an EFI error "invalid parameter". But 20.04 image written with same tools on same computer (running 20.04) works ok. What do I do wrong?

Ant

Comment: Probably the ISO is corrupt.

Comment: Ubuntu iso supports BIOS boot too. Does it work ?

Comment: That ISO works on other computers. So probably not...

Comment: What is the exact error that you get? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Ubuntu is created for many architectures, and recent releases have adjusted how *live* media is booted so all architectures boot the same identical way for a given release; meaning 21.10/impish media will boot differently to 20.04/focal. You've possibly done nothing wrong if you've verified the ISO (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) & it booted on other identical computers; the second test is invalid/incomplete if other machines contained different hardware components - unless you verified the validation of media - so did you? Did the verification complete?

Comment: FYI:  I usually use two other boxes (*one of similar hardware & one rather different*)  to verify the media itself is complete (not just one successful boot & media scan; the self-validation report can be seen with `journalctl`)

Comment: Check your BIOS with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. See if there's a newer one available.